# Getting theta of Line Equation

Tags: math, trigonometry, algebra, pi

Please forgive my lack of knowledge, which i think it's one of those basic formula related to Trigonometry.

Let's look at visual example:
[image]

I have 5 lines, with their line equation (let's say they have zero offset ok)
how can i calculate the Theta of each line equation make (in Pi)?

also I have seen this:
[image]

Are they generated from Theta of line equations? or it's another theory which help to find the theta?
much appreciate your time and effort

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is entirely mathematical.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark why? I can't ask math question?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: `http://math.stackexchange.com` i see what you mean, i thought i can ask any question in stackoverflow. didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For equation

```
y = k * x

tg(Theta) = k
```

and

```
Theta = Arctg(k) //arctangent function
```

[General line equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#General_.28or_standard.29_form)

```
A * x + B * y + C = 0
```

(It is more general than y=ax+b and includes cases of vertical and horizontal lines)

```
Theta = atan2(A, B)
```

(function atan2 or ArcTan2 exists in math libraries of many programming languages)

Comment: thanks for your comment, i didn't get This: `A * x + B * y + C = 0` what's A,B and C? 
also `Theta = atan2(A, B)` is `atan2(A, B)` same as `Arctg(k)`?

Comment: A,B and C are coefficients of the general line equation. For example, `y=2x` form is equivalent to `2x-1y+0=0`.  I've added wiki link. And no, atan2 is special arctangent function with two arguments.